# Single click to open items issue in budgie

Tags: budgie

"Single click to open items" Should select the item if the mouse is over the item. But it does not select the item. Is there an option or a fix?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, you mean `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences click-policy 'single'`, right? It does not really select on hover, just the mouse-over effect. What is exactly the issue, doesn't a single click open the file? btw: what is your budgie/Ubuntu version?

Comment: Thomas, please could you mention ^^^?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the behavior where just hovering on the file/folder would also select the file (unless, of course, if you can edit the source code). To select a file with a click, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Apart from the requirement to press a key for selecting one file, you can employ these keys as usual to select multiple files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> allows you to select additional files, preserving the selection. <kbd>Shift</kbd> allows you to select a range.

So the only difference compared to the default behaviour of "Double click" is that you should be holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> before clicking the file you wish to select.